# Problem understanding references and copies in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

First off, I apologize if I'm not using the right terms in my question title.  It is entirely possible.  I am starting to learn c++, and I will admit I'm having a really tough time with references and copies.  In reference to my code below, I have the following questions:

1. In main.c, is the argument passed to the Carrier.add() function (*it), a reference, or a copy of the plan object that I put in the vector, or something else?
2. When this argument gets added to the Carrier's vector of Plans (inside the carrier class), is a copy added?  How does that work since I didn't supply a copy constructor or tell it to make a copy?  I think it is automatically generated?
3. Please ignore this one if it is too general.  I guess my main problem is that I want/need to understand how it is working, and this is where am having problems trying to find out the answers to my questions on my own.  Is there a way to make visual studio generate the constructors in my actual code the same way that the compiler would, so I could step through them in debug mode to see how it all is working.  Right now when I debug, it is hard for me to tell that a compiler-generated copy constructor is called (if that is what is happening at all).

Here is my code:

main.c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Plan.h"
#include "Carrier.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::vector<Plan> plans;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        Plan p(i);
        plans.push_back(p);
    }

    Carrier c(5);
    for(std::vector<Plan>::iterator it = plans.begin(); it != plans.end(); ++it) {
            //my question is about the line directly below this comment
        c.add(*it);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Plan.h

```
#pragma once

class Plan
{
private:
    int id;
public:
    Plan(int id);
};
```

Plan.cpp

```
#include "Plan.h"

Plan::Plan(int i)
{
    id = i;
}
```

Carrier.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
class Plan;
class Carrier
{
private:
    int id;
    std::vector<Plan> plans;
public:
    Carrier(int i);
    void add(Plan p);
};
```

Carrier.cpp

```
#include "Carrier.h"
#include "Plan.h"

Carrier::Carrier(int i) {
    id = i;
}

void Carrier::add(Plan p) {
    plans.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: The mix of non-standard VC++ extensions and STL is weird...

Comment: The terms in the question title are perfect and this is a pretty well-phrased question. +1.

Comment: @Etienne - Ha. yeah i'm using a book that uses stl and gcc, but i'm on windows, so i'm just using visual studio.  should i not be using stl?

Comment: Mingw is an alternative that you can give a try. There's nothing wrong in using STL.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use the STL. What you should avoid is using `_tmain` (prefer a plain old `int main(int argc, char * argv[])`). And get rid of that stdafx.h, you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Since `Carrier::add` does not take its argument by reference, it is passed a copy. To have it take a reference, change its signature to

```
void Carrier::add(Plan const &p);
```

(2) When you do `push_back`, a copy is created regardless of whether you pass a `Plan` by reference or by value/copy; that's part of the semantics of `std::vector` (and all the other standard containers). The copy constructor is generated automatically by the compiler.

(3) I'm not a VC++ user, but the copy constructor that the compiler will generate is equivalent to

```
Plan::Plan(Plan const &other)
 : id(other.id)  // there's only one member,
                 // but other members would be treated the same
{}
```

In the empty body, you could add a printing statement indicating that the copy constructor is called, but that would not be waterproof; in some cases, C++ is allowed to perform the *copy elision* optimization, meaning that the actual copying is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your first question, that Plan object is passed by value, so it is a **copy** of the object that is passed to the function.

If you wanted a reference, you need to create the function like this:

```
void Carrier::add(Plan const & p)
```

You're passing a const object Plan here because you are not changing anything to it in the function.  This is considered good practice in C++, if you are not going to make changes to an argument and are passing it by reference or pointer for that matter, make it `const`.

In answer to your second question, the container (std::vector) in this case is passed a copy.

Answer (score 2):

> In main.c, is the argument passed to the Carrier.add() function (*it), a reference, or a copy of the plan object that I put in the vector, or something else?

It is a copy because you have declared `add()` as `void add(Plan p);`. If you want to pass a reference then it should be declared as `void add(Plan& p);`.

> When this argument gets added to the Carrier's vector of Plans (inside the carrier class), is a copy added? How does that work since I didn't supply a copy constructor or tell it to make a copy? I think it is automatically generated?

Yes. The compiler generates it for you. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) for more details.

> Is there a way to make visual studio generate the constructors in my actual code the same way that the compiler would, so I could step through them in debug mode to see how it all is working.

To my knowledge you cannot specify it as a setting in Visual studio to include the code for the automatically generated copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

1- `*it` is dereferencing the elements of the `plans` vector and passes them to `c.add` by value. So, that's right, a copy of each element of the `plans` vector is temporarily constructed in variable `p` (argument of `add` method) and then added to the `plans` vector of `Carrier` class.

2- That's right, a copy is added. The default behavior when you do not provide a copy constructor is to copy every attribute of the objects being copied. You can modify this behavior by providing a copy constructor.

3- It would not be difficult to understand how a compiler generated copy-constructor works. Just assume that every attribute of the passed object is getting copied to the object whose copy constructor is getting called.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand `pass-by-value` and `pass-by-reference` you need to know what are references. `References` are like `aliases` to same memory location.

Although the code below has nothing to do with your question, i purposely took a simple example to demonstrate whats happening.

```
#include<iostream>
void foo(int , int & ); //Declaration of foo

void foo(int copy, int &reference)
{
          copy++; // Updates the Local Variable Copy 
          reference++;  // Updates x
}

int main(){
    int x=10;
    int &reftox=x; // reference to x
    foo(x,reftox);
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Output would be `11`. The remaining doubts pertaining to your question has already been answered.